# How to reduce loudness from -7 Lufs to -14 lufs

Tags: volume, youtube

How I can reduce a track Loudness from -7.5 Lufs to -14 Lufs to match youtube sound normalisation

Now I can reduce the output level to match -14 Lufs but I don't know if the method loses sound energy.

Comment: Of course  you lose energy. That is the point of LUFs to stop the loudness problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reduce the output gain by 6.5dB - that will get you from -7.5LUFS to -14LUFS. Job Done.

Comment: Thanks Mark tha what a do but I was not sure that is the right way to do It

Comment: All good mate - please accept the answer if your are happy with it.